# Bluemix can not list docker images

Tags: docker, ibm-cloud

I've successfully logged in bluemix container service via command `ice login` with following output:

```
Authentication with container cloud service at https://api-ice.ng.bluemix.net/v1.0/containers completed successfully
You can issue commands now to the container service

Proceeding to authenticate with the container cloud registry at registry-ice.ng.bluemix.net
Login Succeeded
```

And `ice ps -a` works as well, but when issuing `ice images`, it failed with:

```
$ ice --verbose images
@2015-05-07 13:59:29.221306 - Namespace(cloud=False, local=False, subparser_name='images', verbose=True)
@2015-05-07 13:59:29.221370 - request url: https://api-ice.ng.bluemix.net/v1.0/containers/images/json
@2015-05-07 13:59:30.012412 - Return code: 404   Return reason: NOT FOUND
@2015-05-07 13:59:30.012439 - Req-ID: a382f2f79d54b157
@2015-05-07 13:59:30.012451 - Exit err level = 1
```

Here's the command line version:

```
$ ice version
ICE CLI Version        : 2.0.1 000 2015-03-26T19:51:27
```

Notice that `ice images` works last week.

is there anything changed in the server side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try login to ice with this

```
ice login -a https://api.ng.bluemix.net -H https://api-ice.ng.bluemix.net/v2/containers -R registry-ice.ng.bluemix.net
```

This is what I get when running ice --verbose images

```
bash-3.2$ ice --verbose images
@2015-05-08 14:54:49.692386 - Namespace(cloud=False, local=False,     subparser_name='images', verbose=True)
@2015-05-08 14:54:49.692455 - request url: https://api-ice.ng.bluemix.net/v2/containers/images/json
@2015-05-08 14:54:49.692466 - using bearer token and space id
@2015-05-08 14:54:49.692482 - config.json path: /Users/stanli/.cf/config.json
```

It seems that your ice command was pointing to v1 of the api.

-Stan

Comment: It works. seems it starts to use docker registry v2 API since this month? where can I find the announcement?